# Limit the log in attempts ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, security

Is there a way to limit the amount of login attempts?

I have a password manager which has secure generated passwords, but a thief would get access to these if the person steals my laptop and brute force breaks the much simpler log in password. If, however, there is a limit to five attempts then a 24 hour lock-out, brute force would not be an option for the thief.

Cheers!

Comment: If someone steels your laptop, you don't need to worry, because you use full-disk encryption with a strong password. If not, the thief has access to just anything on your hard disk and limiting login attempts won't help with anything.

Comment: But once this is known, colleag^H^H^H^H^H^H pranksters can just try some random strings in your login prompt, and lock you out of your own PC.

Comment: Also, there is a [delay between passwords attempts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/why-is-there-a-big-delay-after-entering-a-wrong-password/2128#2128) so frontal brute force is rate-limited anyway.

Comment: The password manager's database is hopefully encrypted, so no one will have access to the passwords even if they have physical access and your login password.

Answer (score 6):

Forget it.

If an attacker has physical access to your computer, they can remove the disk and read the content of the disk without ever logging in.

The solution here is full disk encryption, with a reasonably secure pass phrase that is not feasible to guess, in combination with a log on password that is reasonably secure.

You should also define who the attacker is. If it's a thief that stole your *laptop* they're probably after the value of the laptop. They won't spend hours attempting to crack anything; they'll spend minutes probably.

If it's a three letter agency, they may gain access to your laptop to install hardware keyloggers, capturing your password and making any length considerations void.

Comment: "three letter agency", interesting!